# R - concatenate/copy row to last non-empty column of previous row

Tags: r

Take this sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("1","2","3","7", "8"),
                 fruit=c("Appl","e","t","Banan","a"),
                 veg=c(NA,"Carro","Dog","","Kale"),
                 animal=c("",NA,NA,NA,"Cat")) 

id   fruit    veg      animal
1    Appl     <NA>     <blank>
2    e        Carro    <NA>
3    t        Dog      <NA>   
7    Banan    <blank>  <NA>
8    a        Kale     Cat
```

I would like to write a script that checks if the id value of row x is consecutive to row x -1, if so, then concatenate the first column of row x to the last non-empty, non-NA row of row x-1, and copy the rest of the columns over, so that it looks like this:

```
id   fruit    veg      animal
1    Apple    Carrot   Dog
2    <Blank>  <Blank>  <Blank>
3    <Blank>  <Blank>  <Blank>   
7    Banana   Kale     Cat
8    <Blank>  <Blank>  <Blank>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need.

```
df[is.na(df)] = ""
i = 1
while (i < nrow(df) - 1) {
    if (as.numeric(df[i, 1]) + 1 == as.numeric(df[i+1, 1])) {
        j = 4
        while (df[i, j] == "") j = j - 1
        k = 2
        while (df[i+1, k] == "") k = k + 1
        df[i, j] = paste(df[i, j], df[i+1, k], sep="")
        while (j < ncol(df)) {
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
            df[i, j] = df[i+1, k]
        }
        df[i, 1] = df[i+1, 1]
        df = df[-(i+1), ]
    } else {
        i = i + 1
    }
}
```

May not be very efficient because it iterates for all rows. Depends on how many rows you have in the dataset.

Comment: thanks! I had to slightly modify your code to ``` while (i < nrow(df)) ``` but it was exactly what I was looking for!